# What is the proper time used in relativistic non-equilibrium statistical physics?

Tags: special-relativity, statistical-mechanics, relativistic-jets

In the literature one often finds covariant relativistic generalizations of classical non equilibrium statistical equations (Boltzmann, Vlasov, Landau, Fokker-Planck, etc...) but I wonder what is the  meaning of the time which is used. As far as I know, one can only write the interaction between two relativistic charged particles by doing the computation in the proper space-time frame of one of the particles. With three relativistic charged particles I am already wondering about how to tackle the problem of proper time, so for N close to a mole...I am lost.
Since non-equilibrium statistical mechanics is derived from Hamiltonian mechanics, I can reformulate my question as follows. What is the Hamiltonian of N relativistic interacting charged particles ?

Comment: http://www.icmp.lviv.ua/journal/zbirnyk.25/001/art01.pdf "Classical relativistic system of N charges. Hamiltonian description, forms of dynamics, and partition
function" looks as if it answers exactly your question.

Comment: @JohnRennie perhaps you could post that as an answer? (with a brief statement of what the article actually says that answers the question)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky a quick glance at the article convinced me that a brief description would be hard! The fact I found it is more a testament to my Google skills than my deep knowledge of relativistic statistical thermodynamics :-)

Comment: The paper is quite complex, so far my researches to solve the problem has only brought back this paper:

http://www.cft.edu.pl/~laturski/Physica/Gauge-IndependentCanonicalFormulationofRelativisticPlasmaTheory_(IBB,JCH,LAT,1984).pdf

I am not sure I understand how they have avoided the retarded time for each particle ...

Answer (score 2):

Relativistic non-equilibrium statistical physics is done in a field theoretic setting, not in a multiparticle setting. There everything is naturally covariant in space-time coordinates, and the question of proper time does not arise. (Instead one has the preferred time of a coordinate systen comoving with the fluid.)

Note that there is no consistent classical relativistic multiparticle setting; see Currie, Jordan and Sudarshan, Reviews of Modern Physics 35 (1963), 350. Relativistic quantum multiparticle theory is possible in a pure particle framework; see, e.g.,

B.D. Keister and W.N. Polyzou, [Relativistic Hamiltonian Dynamics in Nuclear and Particle Physics](http://arnold-neumaier.at/physfaq/topics/www.physics.uiowa.edu/%7Ewpolyzou/papers/rev.pdf), in: Advances in Nuclear Physics, Volume 20, (J. W. Negele and E.W. Vogt, eds.) Plenum Press 1991.

But it is somewhat awkward to use and I haven't seen any statistical mechanics based on it. The conventional approach to relativistic quantum multiparticle theory is through quantum field theory. For a treatment of relativistic statistical mechanics in these terms see, e.g., the book Calzetta,& Hu, Nonequilibrium quantum field theory. Cambridge University Press (2008).